# Thread-safe read-only alternative to vtkUnstructuredGrid->GetPoint()

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, vtk, point-clouds

I have started working on multithreading and point cloud processing. Problem is i have to implement multithreading onto an existing implementation and there are so many read and write operation so using mutex does not give me enough speed up in terms of performance due to too many read operations from the `grid`.

At the end i modified the code in a way that i can have one `vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>`which holds my point cloud. The only operation the threads have to do is accessing points using [GetPoint](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataSet.html#a98d7b2d041f704e203a885ca6d384507) method. However, it is not thread safe even when you have read-only operation due to smart pointers.

Because of that i had to copy my main Point cloud for each thread which at the end causes memory issues if i have too many threads and big clouds.

I tried to cut point clouds into chunks but then it gets too complicated again when i have too many threads. I can not guarantee optimized amount of points to process for each thread. Also i do neighbour search for each point so cutting point cloud into chunks gets even more complicated because i need to have overlaps for each chunk in order to get proper neighbourhood search.

Since `vtkUnstructuredGrid`is memory optimized i could not replace it with some STL containers. I would be happy if you can recommend me data structures i can use for point cloud processing that are thread-safe to read. Or if there is any other solution i could use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain *using mutex does not give me enough speed up*? In terms of performance, or coding speed?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o in terms of performance. Because during processing  each thread reads from main cloud so many times(because many operation only gives the ids of points then you have to read the position) and then they have to wait for each other. For example, when i have 8 threads i get only double speed up in processing because of that.

Comment: In my experience and also according to the documentation you linked, `GetPoint(vtkIdType id, double x[3])` is thread safe. Can you explain in more details what exactly are you doing that is making it not thread safe?

Comment: @tomj i am actually only reading from memory using `GetPoint`. Even though it says thread safe in the documentation, i get undefined behaviors. From 2014 in the vtk forums they mentioned it is not thread safe because [Certainly I can't use vtkSmartPointer, because it accesses a singleton garbage collection mechanism](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/VTK-in-a-multi-threaded-program-td5726457.html). I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Actually i read with `GetPoint` and also do a neighborhood search with `vtkSmartPointer<vtkOctreePointLocator>` but non of them should modify the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought i post the solution because it was actually my stupitidy. I realized that at one part of my code i was using `double* vtkDataSet::GetPoint(vtkIdType ptId)` version of `GetPoint()` which is not thread safe.

For multithreaded code `void vtkDataSet::GetPoint(vtkIdType id,double x[3])` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with VTK or how it works.

In general, there are various techniques and methods to improve performance in multi-threading environment. The question is vague, so I can only provide a general vague answer.

- **Easy**: In case there are many reads and few writes, use `std::shared_mutex` as it allows multiple reads simultaneously.
- **Moderate**: If the threads work with distinct data most of the time: they access the same data array but at distinct locations - then you can implement a handler that ensures that the threads concurrently work over distinct pieces of data without intersections and if a thread ask to work over a piece of data that is currently being processed, then tell it to work over something else or wait.
- **Hard**: There are methods that allow efficient concurrency via `std::atomic` by utilizing various memory instructions. I am not too familiar with it and it is definitely not simple but you can seek tutorials on it in the internet. As far as I know, certain parts of such methods are still in research-and-development and best practices aren't yet developed.

**P.S.** If there are many reads/writes over the same data... is the implementation even aware of the fact that the data is shared over several threads? Does it even perform correctly? You might end up needing to rewrite the whole implementation.

Comment: Actually after i refactored the code there are not any write operations to same location from the threads but i still have read operations via vtks `getPoint()` which is not thread safe and cause undefined behavior. About your easy implementation suggestion i used mutex every time i read from the point cloud. It does not seem like it allows multiple read simultaneously because i dont get the expected performance improvement based on amount of threads. Can you elaborate more on that please? or direct me to a link?

Comment: @AliKanat for `std::shared_mutex` checkout the [standard C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/). You ought to use the `std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex>` for read operations and use `std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex>` for write operations.

Comment: @AliKanat if switching from `lock_guard/unique_lock` to `shared_lock` doesn't provide sufficient improvement - then it is possible that the bottleneck lies somewhere else. E.g., having 8 cores usually means that you have 4 cores and each core is virtually doubled but it can only partially perform as 2 cores. Or the implementation uses too much RAM access - global memory is shared along all cores, and if you have too many reads/writes to it then parallelizing it might lead to little to no improvement depending on hardware. Multiple cores/threads mostly improve speed of computations not memory.

Comment: I only used regular mutex i will try using `shared_mutex` also. Thank for the detailed explanation. In fact i dont have any write operations. I only have too many read operations but apparent because of vtkSmartPointers i get this issue.